# Determine $\delta$ if $\varepsilon$ $=$ $0.06$ for $\lim_{x \to 1} (2 - 3x)$ $=$ $-1$

Tags: calculus, limits, problem-solving, epsilon-delta

*Determine $\delta$ if $\varepsilon$ $=$ $0.06$ for $\lim_{x \to 1} (2 - 3x)$ $=$ $-1$*

### Book solution:

If $0$ $<$ $|x - 1|$ $<$ $\delta$, then $3|1 - x|$ $<$ $\varepsilon$. $|1-x|$ is the same as $|x-1|$, so $|x-1|$ $<$ $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ is determined by:

> $\delta$ $\leq$ $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ $\leq$ $\frac{0.06}{3}$ $\leq$ $0.02$

### My solution:

If $0$ $<$ $|x - 1|$ $<$ $\delta$, then $3|1 - x|$ $<$ $\varepsilon$. $|1-x|$ is the same as $|x-1|$, so $|x-1|$ $<$ $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ is determined by:

> $\delta$ $\geq$ $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ $\geq$ $\frac{0.06}{3}$ $\geq$ $0.02$

Why?

$3|1 - x|$ $<$ $\varepsilon$ (divide both sides by 3)

$|x - 1|$ $<$ $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ ($|1-x|$ the same as $|x-1|$)

We also know that

$0$ $<$ $|x - 1|$ $<$ $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$

Let $\delta$ $=$ $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$.

The inequality $0$ $<$ $|x - 1|$ $<$ $\delta$ will still be true if $\delta$ $>$ $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ or if it's $\delta$ $=$ $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$. Thus, $\delta$ $\geq$ $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$

**Verification:** ???

$0$ $<$ $|x - 1|$ $<$ $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$

$0$ $<$ $3|x-1|$ $<$ $\varepsilon$

$3|x-1|$ $<$ $\varepsilon$

Comment: You aren't trying to prove if $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ then $|x-a| < \delta$.  You are trying to prove if $|x-a| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.   So sure $|(2-3x)-(-1)|< \epsilon \implies |x-1|< \frac {\epsilon}3 < 500gazillionbillion$ but that doesn't mean $|x-1| < 500gazillionbillion\implies |(2-3x)-(-1)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: What you've shown is that if $\delta\ge\epsilon/3$, then $3|x-1|\lt\epsilon\implies|x-1|\lt\delta$. But you need the implication in the other direction.  Think about it this way: One way to be sure that $\delta\ge\epsilon/3$ is to make $\delta$ extremely large. But then $|x-1|\lt\delta$ even if $x$ is a long ways from $1$. I.e., what @fleablood beat me to saying!

Comment: You are doing it the opposite way. The delta inequality is the fact which should imply the epsilon inequality.

Comment: I've made an attempt to verify my result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *aren't* trying to prove if $|(2-3x)-(-1)| < \epsilon \implies 0 < |x-1| < \delta$.  (That's a trivial statement; we can usually make that statement true by taking very large $\delta$ whether or not our function is continuous.  [not always but usually].)

You are trying to prove if $0 < |x-1| < \delta \implies |(2-3x)-(-1)|\epsilon$ and we are trying to find a $\delta$ where that will work for that $\epsilon$.

.....

To show that a $\delta \ge \frac {\epsilon}3$ won't work, lets suppose $\frac {\epsilon}3 \le |x-1| < \delta$.

Then either $\frac {\epsilon}3 \le x-1 < \delta$ or $\frac {\epsilon}3 \le 1-x < \delta$.

So either $\epsilon \le 3(x-1) < 3\delta$ of $\epsilon  \le 3(1-x) < 3\delta$.

So either $0 < \epsilon \le 3x -3  < 3x -2$ or $0 < \epsilon \le 3-3x$.

So either $0 < \epsilon \le (3x-2) +(-1)$ or $0 < \epsilon \le (2-3x) +1 = (2-3x)-(-1)$.

EIther way we end up with $\epsilon \le |(2-3x) -(-1)|$ and ... we failed.

......

We need to have $\delta \le \frac \epsilon 3$ in order to *force* having $|x-1| <\delta$ to *always* result in $|(2-3x) -(-1)| < \epsilon$.

But as long as $|x-1| < \delta \le \frac \epsilon 3$ we are good.

If $|x-1| < \delta \le \frac \epsilon 3$ then

$|1-x| < \delta \le \frac \epsilon 3$ and so

$-\frac \epsilon 3\le \delta < 1-x < \delta \le \frac \epsilon 3 \implies$

$-\epsilon \le 3\delta < 3-3x = (2-3x) -(-1) < 3\delta\le\epsilon\implies$

$|(2-3x)-(-1)| < 3\delta \le \epsilon$

and we have ... succeeded.

......

For any $\epsilon > 0$ if we pick any $0< \delta \le \frac \epsilon 3$ we will have that if we pick any $x$ so that $|x-1| < \delta$ it will always follow that $|(2-3x) -(-1)| < \epsilon$.

*THAT* is what we needed to show and picking a $\delta > \frac {\epsilon}3$ would not allow us to show that.

=====

> Then how would you get to δ ≤ ε3 in the first place?

Okay... We'd work backwards.  We'd want an argument where the *last* step is

$|(2-3x)-(-1)| < 0.06 =\epsilon$

And the *first* step is $|x-1| < \delta$

SO the *second* to last step is: $-\epsilon = -0.06 < (2-3x) -(-1) < 0.06 = \epsilon$

The third to last step is: $-\epsilon=-0.06 < 3-3x < 0.06 = \epsilon$.

the fourth to last step is: $-\frac {\epsilon}3 = -0.02 < 1-x < 0.02 = \frac \epsilon 3$

Our fifth to last step is: $|1-x| < 0.02=\frac \epsilon 3$

Our sixth to last step is: $|x-1| < 0.2 =\frac \epsilon 3= \delta$.

And the sixth to last step is our first step and we have $\delta = \frac \epsilon 3 = 0.2$.

.....

or alternatively we can work forward with a goal in mind.

We start with $|x-1| < \delta$ and we need that to imply $|(2-3x)-(-1)| < \epsilon$.

So we state $-\delta < x-1 < \delta$ and we need that to imply $|(2-3x)-(-1)| < \epsilon$.

So so state $1-\delta < x < 1+\delta$ and we need that to imply $|(2-3x)-(-1)| < \epsilon$.

So we state $3-3\delta < 3x < 3 + 3\delta$ and we need that to imply $|(2-3x)-(-1)| < \epsilon$.

So we state $-3+3\delta > -3x >-3 -3\delta$ or in other words $-3 -\delta < -3x < -3+\delta$ and we need that to imply $|(2-3x)-(-1)| < \epsilon$.

SO we state $-1 - 3\delta < 2-3x < -1+3\delta$ and we need that to imply $|(2-3x)-(-1)| < \epsilon$.

So we state $-3\delta <(2-3x) -(-1) < 3\delta$ and we need that to imply $|(2-3x)-(-1)| < \epsilon$.

So we state $|(2-3x)-(-1)| < 3\delta$ and we need that to imply $|(2-3x)-(-1)| < \epsilon$.

Well, if $3\delta = \epsilon$ it will imply *exactly* that!

So if $\delta =\frac \epsilon 3$ we have

$|x-1| < \delta = \frac \epsilon 3$ will directly imply that $|(2-3x) -(-1)| < 3\delta =\epsilon$.

Comment: Then how would you get to $\delta$ $\leq$ $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ in the first place?

Comment: Just pick one.  Let $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}3$ will do. So will any $\delta: 0 < \delta \le \frac {\epsilon}3$.  If you wan't to play it safe and $\epsilon = 0.06$ let $\delta = 0.0000000000001$.  Then $|x-1| < 0.0000000000001 \implies |(2-3x)-(-1) < 0.0000000000003 < 0.06 = \epsilon$. But you don't have to be so ridicuolous.  If you let $\delta = 0.02$ that's good enough.  $|x-1|< 0.02\implies 0.98 < x < 1.02\implies |(2-3x)-(-1)| < 0.06$ is easy enough to show.  But if $|x-1| \ge 0.02$ we have eith $0.98\ge x$ or $1.02 \le x$ and we can end up with $|(2-3x)-(-1)| \ge 0.06$. That's no good.

Comment: Is $\delta$ $\leq$ $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ a consequence of Is $\delta$ $=$ $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$?

Comment: Oh... I see what you are asking.... I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: If $0< \delta_1 < \delta_2 = \frac {\epsilon}3$.  And if $|x-1| < \frac {\epsilon}3 \implies |(2-3x)-(-1)| < \epsilon$ then $|x-1|< \delta_1 \implies |x-1|< \frac {\epsilon}3 \implies |(2-3x)-(-1)| < \epsilon$.   So *any* $0< \delta_1< \frac {\epsilon}3$ will do.  But so will $\delta_2 = \frac {\epsilon} 3$.  We can't have any $\delta_3 >\frac {\epsilon}3$ as $|x-1| < \delta_3 \not \implies |(2-3x) -(-1)|< \epsilon$ as any $x$ so that $\frac {\epsilon }3 \le |x-1| < \delta_3 \implies \epsilon \le |(2-3x)-(-1)| < 3\delta_3$ and that's not an acceptable result.

Comment: $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}3$ is the *largest* acceptable $\delta$ in this case.  We *could* choose a *smaller* $\delta$ if we wanted to.  But $\delta=\frac {\epsilon}3$ is a value that will work.

Comment: I didn't get this: "So we state $-3 + 3\delta$ $>$ $-3x$ $>$ $-3 -3\delta$ or in other words $-3 -\delta$ $<$ $-3x$ $<$ $3 +\delta$ ". Could you tell how you got there?

Comment: It was a typo. It should be $-3+3\delta > -3x > -3-3\delta$ or $-3-3\delta < -3x < -3 + 3\delta$.  I just switched the order to go from lowest to highest (after I had switched them when I multiplied by a negative number)

Answer (score 0):

If you vary $x$ by $\pm\delta$, it is clear that $2-3x$ will vary by $\mp3\delta$. Hence any $\delta\le\dfrac\epsilon3$ should do.